# Is it Undefined Behavior to write `return {data, uninitialized_copy(b, e, data)};` in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, undefined-behavior

Hi i am reading an example of how to define our own vector like class without using templates from one of the books. Now here there is one function which is defined as follows:

```
pair<string *, string*> StrVec::alloc_n_copy(const string *b, const string *e)
{
   auto data = alloc.allocate(e - b);
   return {data, uninitialized_copy(b, e, data)};

}
```

Now my question is that is the above return statement undefined behavior? For example i know that the following below statement is undefined behavior:

```
std::cout<< i << ++i<<std::endl;
```

Since this example statement is undefined, shouldn't the `return` statement also be undefined?, since it also changes the value of the variable `data`.

Comment: what is `uninitialized_copy` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Probably https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy

Comment: What should be undefined about it? It does change the value the data pointer points to, but not the data variable itself, so it is OK.

Comment: you cant draw conclusions about defined / undefined behavior merely by similarities in syntax

Comment: `std::cout << i << ++i << std::endl;` is well defined since C++17 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `std::cout << i << ++i << std::endl;` is that `i` is used twice in the same expression and once it is modified. There are numerous questions and answers around this topic, so I just refer to them.

In your code

```
return {data, uninitialized_copy(b, e, data)};
```

`data` is not modified. It doesn't matter if you take the value of `data` before `uninitialized_copy` is called, or whether you return the value of `data` after a copy of it has been passed to `unitialized_copy`.

Maybe thats the detail you missed. `std::unitialized_copy` is:

```
template< class InputIt, class ForwardIt >
ForwardIt uninitialized_copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, ForwardIt d_first );
```

ie all parameters are taken by value.

Its similar as in

```
 int foo(int x) { return 2*x; }

 int bar(int y)  { return y + foo(y); }
```

Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I get your example. My next question is when we use unintialized_copy() lets say like `uninitialized_copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),data);` then isn't the iterator `data` is incremented the same number of times as there are elements in the input range? For example if there are 4 elements in the input range then data will be incremented four times to point to those locations so that elements can be constructed there. So isn't incrementing `data` means changing `data`? Or is it not the case since data is passed by value?

Comment: @JasonLiam `d_first` is passed by value. What happens inside `uninitialized_copy` is a different story, and I have to admit that I didn't really understand what it does, it wasn't strictly necessary to answer the question

Answer (score 2):

You are right that

```
std::cout<< i << ++i<<std::endl;
```

<strike>is</strike> was UB (prior to C++17) because `i` is read *and* modified between sequence points.

However

```
return {data, uninitialized_copy(b, e, data)};
```

does not change `data`. It only changes the elements `data` points to.

Comment: In addition `{.., ..}` has sequence points (and left-to-right evaluation).

Comment: @churill also we are passing `data` by value and so a copy of `data` will be given which means when `data` is incremented it will be the temporary copy that will be incremented and not the original one. Thanks.